# sharepoint 2010 login redirection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, login

i have sharepoint 2010 server installed.

problem:

If i send a url http://intranet/Pages/mypage.aspx to a user, the user gets to the page but has to login to see it, so he does login but gets redirected to   http://intranet/Pages/default.aspx

question:

how can i get the user to stay on http://intranet/Pages/mypage.aspx after he logs in?

http://intranet/Pages/mypage.aspx could be any page actually.

Comment: Are you using windows login or FBA login?

Comment: i do use Windows and NTML and anonymous access

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to a URL and - not - being redirected following authentication is standard out of the box IIS behaviour so the answer should be "do nothing" to achieve this.

Are you sure that there aren't any page customisations (such as JavaScript) that might redirect users?

Answer (score 0):

I think some js code can help the redirection of the webpage

Comment: It would be great if you could give us an example of the JavaScript you have in mind. Also, very terse answers like this get flagged automatically by the system. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By Default Share Point has second option if you are having that page. For Example I want to access a page like `http://intranet/_layouts/settings.aspx` i can get that page directly if that page exists and if iam having access to that page.

If you want any page like `http://intranet/pages/mypage.aspx`, you can make that page as home page by using the designer.

Comment: no i do not want mypage.aspx to be the HP.

Comment: yes i want any url to stay only on that page when the user login

Comment: I think Sharepoint is having that feature by default

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var curentUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldName: 'JobTitle',
debug: false
});
if (curentUser.search(/JobTitle/i)!=-1)
   location="/Pages/mypage.aspx "
});
</script>
```

This redirect by JobTitle field and with using jquery SPServices.

Comment: Add this code in master page.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what is JobTitle for?

Comment: and can you explain what this script does? thanks

Comment: fieldName: 'JobTitle' -- This get from user profile. curentUser.search(/userformypage/i) -- if this field equal "userformypage" it redirecting to mypage.aspx

Comment: Wait what? Put this in the masterpage and the user won't be able to navigate to any site at all, it'll just always redirect to mypage.aspx...